# Перевод систем счисления на си

Tags: c

Всем привет, можете помочь решить задачу? Пытался сделать сам - работает, но не всегда правильно.

Дано число в системе счисления по основанию A. Нужно перевести его в систему
счисления по основанию A<sup>B</sup> .

Input
Со стандартного устройства ввода вводятся натуральные числа A, B и число L – длина
записи числа в системе счисления по основанию A. Гарантируется, что L кратно B и не
превышает 10000.

Во второй строке содержится L цифр – исходное число в системе счисления с
основанием A. A<sup>B</sup>  не превышает 36 (всегда хватает цифр и латинских букв для
представления преобразованного числа).

Output
Нужно выдать на стандартное устройство вывода исходное число в системе счисления
по основанию A<sup>B</sup> .

Sample Input
2 4 32
00111011100101110110011011001111

Sample Output
3B9766CF

Вот код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

char Scale[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

int dig2int(char d)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 36; i++) if (Scale[i] == d) return i;
}

char* convert(char* n, int from, int to)
{
    int i, j, l, p, k;
    char* buf;
    l = strlen(n);
    p = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) p = p * from + dig2int(n[i]);
    buf = (char*)calloc(100, 1);
    k = 99;
    l = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        j = p % to;
        buf[k--] = Scale[j];
        l++;
        p = p / to;
        if (p == 0) break;
    }
    j = 0;
    k++;
    while (1)
    {
        buf[j++] = buf[k++];
        if (k == 100) break;
    }
    buf = (char*)realloc(buf, (l + 1));
    return buf;
}

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int l, sourceNS, resultPow, resultNS, numberInt;

    scanf("%d %d %d", &sourceNS, &resultPow, &l);

    char* numberStr = (char*)calloc(l, sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", numberStr);

    resultNS = pow(sourceNS, resultPow);
    printf("%s", convert(numberStr, sourceNS, resultNS));
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: `Пытался сделать сам`  - так покажите попытки, чтобы было от чего плясать

Comment: @MBo отправил код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код переводит только короткие числа (и не проверяет, что запись подходит под систему A - но вроде условие это гарантирует).

То, что целевая система счисления A^B, облегчает задачу - нам не требуется работать с длинными числами. Нужно только обрабатывать кусочки входной строки длиной B, получая одну выходную цифру, и это можно делать слева направо. Промежуточные результаты будут невелики.

Для данного примера

```
0011   1011  1001  0111  0110  0110  1100  1111
 3      B     9      7     6     6    C     F
```